# how to setup quartz in cluster environment

Tags: spring-boot, quartz

I am using Spring boot 2 with quartz setup with MY SQL database. Schedulers are created using REST API. everything is working fine until the service reboot.  But when service reboot it does not start schedulers automatically. Is there any way to achieve this via configuration or manually with code at startup ?

Comment: Whenever you create scheduler, save them in persistent storage like DB or files. In case of reboot or app restart, read the schedulers and schedule them back.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz will start all the process automatically at boot up. It was configuration issue.